# Is there a way to access the resource folder of other plugin from current plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am using following code to copy icons which are available in resource folder of Plug-in "A" to a local folder. This works absolutely fine. Now I want to know if there is way to copy icons from resource folder of other plugin say (plugin B). I have to retain the copy logic in plugin A only. Is there a way to access the resource folder of other plugin from current plug-in ?

```
File objectDir = new File(directory + "/icons/");

    if (!objectDir.exists()) {
        objectDir.mkdirs();
    }

    InputStream inStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;

    try {

        File bfile = new File(directory + "/icons/validation.png");
        inStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/icons/viewAsHTML.png");   
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int length;
        // copy the file content in bytes
        while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

            outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

        }

        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();

        System.out.println("File is copied successful!");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "plugin" ?

Comment: I am working on eclipse rcp plugin project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get at a resource in another plugin by using the `platform:/plugin/` mechanism:

```
url = new URL("platform:/plugin/your.plugin.package.pluginB/icons/validation.png");
InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```